# Regex Matching other values if input value is blank or not found in the range, in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets, I have data from a registration form in Tab 1. In Tab 2, im trying to get an array of results according to multiple filters.

The problem is with one of the filters where the field data is stored this way in each cell:

> "**Position**: Cook, **Experiencia**: 1 to 3 months, **Specialty**:
> Bistro
>
> **Position**: Cashier, **Experiencia**: 1 to 3 months, **Specialty**: Bistro
>
> **Position**: Dishwasher, **Experiencia**: 3 months to a 1 year, **Specialty**: Seafood"

And then I can have another response as this:

> "**Position**: Cashier, **Experiencia**: 3 to 5 years, **Specialty**:
> Seafood"

So depending on each form response, the values that they input for each variable(**Position**,**Experiencia**,**Specialty**) may change, as well as the numbers of lines.

Objetive: Being able to Filter and RegexMatch according to what ever value I input for each variable (even if it is blank),

What I have accomplished so far is concatenating the 3 the fields I want to look up and then doing a RegexMatch. The formula successfully finds the row where the 3 variables are a match.

Problem: Whenever the field in the middle is blank, the formula breaks because it concatenates something it won't find. But still, I need it to look up even if this field is blank, just considering every other option.

This is the formula that I'm currently using. As you can see, it uses data from form submissions in the specified column ('Registration Form'!L2:L), to RegexMatch it with a CONCATENATE of 3 fields where it gets the same format, and IF any of those 3 fields is blank, it replaces the field with "".

This is the formula:

`=filter('Registration Form'!A2:V, REGEXMATCH('Registration Form'!L2:L,CONCATENATE(if(B7="","",CONCATENATE("Position: ",B7,", ")),if(B8="","",CONCATENATE("Experiencia: ",B8,", ")),if(B9="","",CONCATENATE("Specialty: ",B9)))))`

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Uir-xVfbBh9uedG7fF_Q2m4wNMGddJb9xkKBVg61vKg/edit?usp=sharing)

And this is a sample of how I input the data that it has to filter

| Variables | Input |
| --- | --- |
| Position | Cashier |
| Experiencia | 1 to 3 months |
| Specialty | Bistro |

Comment: Show your sample input and desired output. Post those data as text table as well as you may share a sample file.

Comment: @Harun24hr, I have updated with your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
=QUERY('Registration Form'!A2:V,
   "where 0=0"&
    IF(B2="",," and L contains '"&B2&"'")&
    IF(B3="",," and L contains '"&B3&"'")&
    IF(B4="",," and L contains '"&B4&"'"))
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. In case you could help me with this, I have added a part two to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77546259/regex-match-a-string-or-any-other-greater-value-string-in-google-sheets

Answer (score 1):

### ALTERNATIVE SOLUTION

I made a slight tweak to your existing formula:

```
=filter('Registration Form'!A2:V,REGEXMATCH('Registration Form'!L2:L,CONCATENATE(if(B2="","",CONCATENATE("Position: ",B2,", ")),if(B3="","(.*?)",CONCATENATE("Experiencia: ",B3,", ")),if(B4="","",CONCATENATE("Specialty: ",B4)))))
```

The only difference with this formula from your existing one is that I added a regex on the second IF statement:

```
if(B3="","(.*?)",CONCATENATE("Experiencia: ",B3,", "))
```

This allows the REGEXMATCH function to detect this particular IF statement as optional, i.e. even if B3 is left blank, the entire filter function will still work as it only require values from the B2 or B4 cells.

### OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this answers your issue, or if there are some things that needs further clarification, so that I can adjust my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow this works perfectly as needed. "(.*?)" was the solution. Thanks

Comment: As an additional question, I was wondering what would be the solution for the field "EXPERIENCE" when I input "3 months to 1 year" for example, but I need it to return "3 months to 1 year" or any higher experience than that. The problem is that this is text and not a number so I'm not really sure.

Comment: Good question; that might be tricky to do within a single formula, since the time range for "Experience" is inputted as a text string, and the filter function only strictly checks for entries that matches.

Comment: Do you reckon there is a way of input multiple text strings with an IF function inside? For example, if 3 months to 1 year, consider 3 months to 1 year, 1 year to 3 years, etc...
Let me know if I should put this in a separate thread.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, it would be better if you can post a separate question for this specific case so that other members of the community would be able to help you out. Also, while it might be possible to put multiple IF statements for the different text strings, there may be a better workaround for it.